# Sql stored procedure combining like materials and adding lengths together

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Stored procedure that looks through SQL tables, then gives me the material and its length.  What I am wanting is the query results to only show the material 1 time, and have all the lengths be added to its material.  I am including the stored procedure and a snapshot of the results I am getting.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MaterialLengthByMachine] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Machine char (20) = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @root hierarchyID;

    SELECT @root= Node
    FROM dbo.BOM
    WHERE BOM.PartNo=@Machine

    SELECT dbo.Components.Material, dbo.Components.[Length]
    FROM
            dbo.Components AS ParentComponents INNER JOIN
            dbo.BOM AS ParentBOM ON ParentComponents.PartNo = ParentBOM.PartNo INNER JOIN
            dbo.BOM AS PartBOM INNER JOIN
            dbo.Components ON PartBOM.PartNo = dbo.Components.PartNo ON ParentBOM.Node = PartBOM.Node.GetAncestor(1)

    WHERE 

         (PartBOM.Node.GetAncestor(PartBOM.Node.GetLevel() -1) = @root)

   GROUP BY dbo.Components.Material, dbo.Components.[Length]

END
```

Below are the results I am getting, for example I want the 16-4 cable to only be listed 1 time but all the 16-4 lengths to be added together and 1 total length given.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) the lengths.  So add the SUM() keyword around the length in your select: `dbo.Components.[Length]` → `SUM(dbo.Components.[Length])`.

Then you'll also need to remove the `GROUP BY dbo.Components.[Length]`, since that will group by each length, and you only want to group by Material.

Should look something like the following:

```
SELECT dbo.Components.Material, SUM(dbo.Components.[Length])
FROM
        dbo.Components AS ParentComponents INNER JOIN
        dbo.BOM AS ParentBOM ON ParentComponents.PartNo = ParentBOM.PartNo INNER JOIN
        dbo.BOM AS PartBOM INNER JOIN
        dbo.Components ON PartBOM.PartNo = dbo.Components.PartNo ON ParentBOM.Node = PartBOM.Node.GetAncestor(1)

WHERE 

     (PartBOM.Node.GetAncestor(PartBOM.Node.GetLevel() -1) = @root)

GROUP BY dbo.Components.Material
```

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted, I gave you an upvote but it does not show, thank you for your help

Comment: @ronnogal Great, glad I could help!

Comment: I have one issue I just ran into today, so I have 2 tables set up one is BOM the other is Components, as you can see from the SELECT everything is pulling from Components, so when I do SUM function it only adds the length for a Qty of 1 part, I want it to add the length for the amount of parts use that material, The only issue is Qty is located in the table BOM but everytime I try to do a JOIN it errors out the bottom 2 INNER JOINS on my FROM, is it possible to do a SUM from dbo.Components.Length and dbo.BOM.Qty

Comment: @ronnogal I didn't really look at your FROM, but it seems strange to me that you are specifying some of the join keys but no the PartBOM join?  Is this T-SQL?  This might also be less confusing if you used the alias's you've created, since it looks like you are joining the same two tables twice for some reason.
The issue in your comment might be worth creating a new question for, it's hard to answer without specifying what error you are getting.

Comment: @ronnogal My guess however would that you would want something like `SUM(dbo.Components.[Length] * dbo.BOM.Qty)`, but I'm not totally sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes I am new to learning programming, so the joins you see are copied from another procedure that someone who I used to work with made, I figured as much with your example but when i try that my joins error out, I was considering a new question but with my limited experience I wasn't to sure how to word it. I kind of got forced into this programming stuff but now that I am learning more am really enjoying it. Thank you for your help and no T-SQL I am using SSMS

Comment: @ronnogal No worries, glad you are enjoying programming!  FYI if you are using SSMS, you are likely working with MSSQL (Microsoft SQL) which uses a flavor of SQL (Structured Query Language) called [TSQL or Transact-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL).

Comment: Oh yes we are definitely using MSSQL, so good to know it is TSQL language, thanks again for all you help